# vlookup for unsorted data does not work

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

i have a table as following, i want to use vlookup but it does not work.
[image]

the format cell of column b and c is text. i wany to find the text in column B from column C.
my formula is:

```
=VLOOKUP(F5,B:C,1,FALSE)
f5=مركز بهداشت دانشگاه تهران
```

but it returns: #n/a
 when i want to find column C from column B, it works well.
please help me. what should i do? is there any mismatch with arabic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`K_B`'s explanation of why your formula doesn't work is correct, you can't use `VLookup` to search column `C` and return from column `B`

You can use `INDEX` and `MATCH` instead, like this

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(F5,C:C,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Arabic speaker, but based on what you are saying, you have a value in cell F5 which you want to lookup in column B and return the corresponding value from column C.
Assuming that is correct, then your formula should read

```
=vlookup(F5, B:C, 2, FALSE)
```

However, that would not cause #n/a to be returned.
It does not look to me like the value given for F5 exists in column B in your example data - can you confirm?

Comment: i exactly copy the cell value of column C into F5.

Comment: This is the problem then - the lookup is performed on Column B, not column C, hence why it is returning #N/A. If you can, just swap column B and C around and your formula will work. If you cannot change the column order you can use an INDEX & MATCH combination as shown here - http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/excel-vlookup-index-match.php

Answer (score 0):

The formula requires the text to be found to be in the 1st column from the second argument (`B:C` in your case).

Then it will return the value from the ith column to you where i is the 3rd argument of the formula (`1` in your case).

This will only work 1 way (Search in B, return from C) and never the other way (search in C return from B).

If you require to work from the other way around you will have to either put the columns in the opposite order OR fill column D with `=B1` etc... and use your formula on `C:D`.

Now whenever the searched text isnt present in your first column the result will always be `#n/a`